# Debugging Errors In STS

Tags: spring, debugging, spring-tool-suite, sts

I'm unable to debug in **Spring Tool Suite (STS 3.9.6)** due to the below error message. Can someone tell me what the problem is? so that I can resolve it.

- Error Message:

> Unable to install breakpoint in [Module name in the
> Package]$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB $$98f254b2 due to missing line number
> attributes. Modify complier options to generate line number
> attributes.
>
> Reason:  Absent Line Number Information

Also, if anyone can guide me on how to resolve the issue, it would be very helpful.

Thanks,
Chaitanya

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that **Add Line Number Attributes to generated class files** is Checked in your project properties ?

Project Properties/Preferences > **Java Compiler** > Classfile Generation (section) > **Add Line Number Attributes to generated class files (used by the debugger)** > **Apply** > Ok

Comment: Hi Mohtadi,Thank you for your help.  I have applied the changes, the error continues to show up. No Change is the  error message.